# Как в переменную записать исходный код страницы?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Как в переменную записать исходный код страницы? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: var html: string = '<!DOCTYPE HTML....';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

возможно так:

```
 var
s:string;
begin
s:=idhttp1.get('http://какой-то сайт');
```